# socket.io : how to emit a response when all client request are done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, websocket, socket.io

I use socket.io and [node-google](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google) package to retrieve google search results and send theme to socket.io clients, now i want to know if there is a way to open google request synchronously (in sequential order) and emit a socket to the clients when all search request are done ?

here is my code :

```
// Load google package
var google = require('google');
// Load socket.io package
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

// on connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected !');

    // on request
    socket.on('request', function (keywords) {

        keywords.forEach(function(entry, index){

            // get results
            google.resultsPerPage = 10;
            google.tld = 'fr';
            var nextCounter = 0;

            // how to make google function sync 
            google(entry, function (err, next, links){
                if (err) console.error('-----\n' + err + '\n-----');

                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {

                    res = links[i].title + links[i].description;

                    if(res){
                        socket.emit('response', res);
                    }

                }

                if (nextCounter < 4) {
                    nextCounter += 1;
                    if (next) next();
                }
            });

            // all search keywords are done (not working)
            if(index === keywords.length - 1){
                socket.emit('response', '------ all done ------');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Thanx :)

Comment: Not really sure what you want. Are you trying to send back response to client after all keywords have been searched?

Comment: no i want to send back response after each keyword have been searched